# Python emulate clicking number button

Tags: python, numbers, pyautogui, pynput

i have problem with clicking number button in python, when i try to simulate click (whatever button I like), it works but when i try to put Key.number it doesn't works. (bottom line's of code)

```
import pyautogui
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyboardController
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller as MouseController
from pynput import keyboard as KeyboardManager
import random
stawianie = False

# Mouse controller
mouse = MouseController()
# Keyboard controller
keyboard = KeyboardController()

def on_press(key):
    pass

def on_release(key):
    global stawianie
    if key == KeyboardManager.Key.f8:
        stawianie = True
    if key == KeyboardManager.Key.f9:
        stawianie = False
    if key == KeyboardManager.Key.f10:
        SystemExit()
        return False

with KeyboardManager.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
listener = KeyboardManager.Listener(
    on_press=on_press,
    on_release=on_release)
listener.start()

while True:
    if stawianie:
        a = random.randint(1,2)
        if a == 1:
            # PRESS NUMBER BUTTON HERE
            keyboard.press(Key.)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using keyboard.press() the parameter needs to have '' around it, keyboard.press('.')